# Add specific border styling and spacing that differs for the table, tr and cells

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I was wondering if it was possible, with html and/or CSS, to collapse only tr with he table's outline, while having different border styles for the table's outline and trs, and the tds and ths.

I know this is complicated, so if this can make it clearer, here's a drawing of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `border-collapse` applies only to the whole table, and it is not a valid property for `tr` or `td` elements so you cannot apply it to those to get a different spacing.

However you can “fake” it by adding the cell content into a div and using it for some of the styling:

- Apply the outer table styling to the `table` as normal
- Apply the row styling to the top and bottom borders of the `th` / `td` cells
- Apply the "cell" styling to the divs inside the `th` & `td`s.

**Working Example:**

```css
table {
  border: 6px solid lightgray;
  border-right-color: gray;
  border-bottom-color: gray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border-top: 5px solid gray;
}
tr:not(:last-child) td{
  border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
}

th .cell,
td .cell {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px ridge lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><div class="cell">First Name</div></th>
    <th><div class="cell">Last Name</div></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="cell">John</div></td>
    <td><div class="cell">Smith</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="cell">Jane</div></td>
    <td><div class="cell">Doe</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. Though if you don't mind, what does tr:not(:last-child) mean? and why the : and the () ? thanks for the great answer.

Comment: @manouna Glad to help! The CSS selector `tr:not(:last-child)` selects all `tr` element except for the last one - we are using this to add the border to the bottom of the `td` s in the tr, but the last tr is next to the bottom of the table so it doesn't need a border. You might not need it (in this example you don't actually need it), but I included it in case you need to set the top and bottom borders separately for some reason. You can see more about the [not() pseudo-class here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Answer (score 0):

Found a way by just adding an hr and a minuscule tr between both trs.

```
 hr {
  border: 4px outset rgb(207, 172, 179);
  width: 443px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 388px;
  left: 35px;
 }
 
 tr#mini {
   border: none;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;margin-top: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   height: 8px;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<table id="tableau" class="nomaltext">
  <tr>
    <th>
      25g
    </th>
    <th>
      50g
    </th>
    <th>
      75g
    </th>
    <th>
      100g
    </th>
    <th>
      Personnalisé (min. 120g)
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="mini">
    <hr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      5,99$
    </td>
    <td>
      8,99$
    </td>
    <td>
      13,80$
    </td>
    <td>
      7,40$
    </td>
    <td>
      11¢/gramme
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```